# SwiftUI and CloudKit asynchronous data loading

Tags: swiftui, cloudkit

I'm fetching a large number of `Tool` objects from iCloud using CloudKit when my app's main screen appears, and I'm running these objects through a filter. The `Tool` array is stored in a `ToolViewModel` object `toolVM` inside an `ObservableObject` class named `UserData`.

This is my ViewModel and my View code:

```
class ToolViewModel: InstrumentViewModel {
    @Published var tools = [Tool]()

    func filter(searchString: String, showFavoritesOnly: Bool) -> [Tool] {
        let list = super.filter(searchString: searchString, showFavoritesOnly: showFavoritesOnly)
        return list.map{ $0 as! Tool }.sorted()
    }

    func cleanUpCategories(from category: String) {
        super.cleanUpCategories(instruments: tools, from: category)
    }
}

struct ToolList: View {
    // @ObservedObject var toolVM = ToolViewModel()
    @ObservedObject var userData: UserData
    @State private var searchString = ""
    @State private var showCancelButton: Bool = false

    var filteredTools: [Tool] {
        userData.toolVM.filter(searchString: searchString, showFavoritesOnly: userData.showFavoritesOnly)
    }

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                // Search view
                SearchView(searchString: $searchString, showCancelButton: $showCancelButton)
                .padding(.horizontal)

                // Tool list
                List {
                    ForEach(filteredTools) { tool in
                        NavigationLink(destination: ToolDetail(tool: tool, userData: self.userData)) {
                            ToolRow(tool: tool)
                        }
                    } // ForEach ends
                    .onDelete(perform: onDelete)
                } // List ends
            } // VStack ends
            .navigationBarTitle("Tools")
        } // NavigationView ends
        .onAppear() {
            if self.userData.toolVM.tools.isEmpty {
                // Tools (probably) haven't been loaded yet (or are really empty), so try it
                self.userData.updateTools()
            }
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

This is the ViewModel's superclass (as I have two more similar ViewModels, I introduced this):

```
class InstrumentViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var categories = [InstrumentCategory]()
    @Published var instrumentCategories = [String: [Instrument]]()

    func filter(searchString: String, showFavoritesOnly: Bool) -> [Instrument] {
        var list = [Instrument]()
        for category in categories {
            if category.isSelected && instrumentCategories[category.name] != nil {
                if searchString == "" {
                    list += showFavoritesOnly ? instrumentCategories[category.name]!.filter { $0.isFavorite } : instrumentCategories[category.name]!
                } else {
                    list += showFavoritesOnly ? instrumentCategories[category.name]!.filter { $0.isFavorite && $0.contains(searchString: searchString) } : instrumentCategories[category.name]!.filter { $0.contains(searchString: searchString) }
                }
            }
        }
        return list
    }

    func setInstrumentCategories(instruments: [Instrument]) {
        var categoryStrings = Set<String>()
        for instrument in instruments {
            categoryStrings.insert(instrument.category)
        }
        for categoryString in categoryStrings.sorted() {
            categories.append(InstrumentCategory(name: categoryString))
        }
    }
}
```

This is my UserData class:

```
final class UserData: ObservableObject {
    @Published var showFavoritesOnly = false

    @Published var toolVM = ToolViewModel()

    func updateTools() {
        DataHelper.loadFromCK(instrumentType: .tools) { (result) in
            switch result {
            case .success(let loadedInstruments):
                self.toolVM.tools = loadedInstruments as! [Tool]
                self.toolVM.setInstrumentCategories(instruments: loadedInstruments)
                self.toolVM.instrumentCategories = Dictionary(grouping: self.toolVM.tools, by: { $0.category })
                debugPrint("Successfully loaded instruments of type Tools and initialized categories and category dictionary")
            case .failure(let error):
                debugPrint(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And last but not least the helper class that actually loads the data from iCloud:

```
struct DataHelper {
    static func loadFromCK(instrumentType: InstrumentCKDataTypes, completion: @escaping (Result<[Instrument], Error>) -> ()) {
        let predicate = NSPredicate(value: true)
        let query = CKQuery(recordType: instrumentType.rawValue, predicate: predicate)
        getCKRecords(instrumentType: instrumentType, forQuery: query, completion: completion)
    }

    private static func getCKRecords(instrumentType: InstrumentCKDataTypes, forQuery query: CKQuery, completion: @escaping (Result<[Instrument], Error>) -> ()) {
        CKContainer.default().publicCloudDatabase.perform(query, inZoneWith: CKRecordZone.default().zoneID) { results, error in
            if let error = error {
                DispatchQueue.main.async { completion(.failure(error)) }
                return
            }
            guard let results = results else { return }
            switch instrumentType {
            case .tools:
                DispatchQueue.main.async { completion(.success(results.compactMap { Tool(record: $0) })) }
            case .drivers:
                DispatchQueue.main.async { completion(.success(results.compactMap { Driver(record: $0) })) }
            case .adapters:
                DispatchQueue.main.async { completion(.success(results.compactMap { Adapter(record: $0) })) }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The issue I encounter is the following:
The view initializes before the data was loaded from iCloud. I initialize the `tools` variable in the ViewModel with an empty `Tool` array. Therefore no tools are displayed when the view appears.

Although `tools` is a `@Published` variable, the view won't reload after the asynchronous iCloud loading process has finished. This is the behavior I would expect. As soon as I start typing some search string into the search field, the tools do appear. It's only about the very first loading.

What won't work either is to initialize the `toolVM` in the `UserData` initializer, as I won't get access to it from the asynchronous loading closure.

Funny enough: If I move the `toolVM` variable into the view itself as `@ObservedObject` (you can see it in my View, I commented this line out in the code), the view *will* reload after data load is done. Unfortunately this is not an option for me, as I need access to the `toolVM` ViewModel in other parts of the app, therefore I store it in my UserData class.

I assume it has something to do with the asynchronous loading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ToolViewModel` reference is not changed, so nothing published at `UserData` level. Here is possible solution - force publish intentionally:

```
DataHelper.loadFromCK(instrumentType: .tools) { (result) in
    switch result {
    case .success(let loadedInstruments):
        self.toolVM.tools = loadedInstruments as! [Tool]
        self.toolVM.setInstrumentCategories(instruments: loadedInstruments)
        self.toolVM.instrumentCategories = Dictionary(grouping: self.toolVM.tools, by: { $0.category })
        debugPrint("Successfully loaded instruments of type Tools and initialized categories and category dictionary")

        self.objectWillChange.send()      // << this !!

    case .failure(let error):
        debugPrint(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

-

**Alternate** solution is to separate `ToolViewModel` dependent part of `ToolList` view into dedicated smaller child view with observed `ToolViewModel` and pass reference in it from `userData`.